# How to apply operations of comparaison (min,gt) to a ndarray of Theano variables?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, pymc3

I'm trying to do a Bayesian calibration with PyMC3; however, my model function requires to compare arrays of Theano variables.

**Here a illustration of the problem:**

```py
import theano.tensor as tt

 # create an example of array of Theano variables
a=np.array([tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*1,tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*2])

 # try to apply operations of comparison

tt.gt(a,1)

->AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert [Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0 Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}.0] to TensorType', <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)*

a>1

-> TypeError: Variables do not support boolean operations.
```

Does anyone know how to manage with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a NumPy `ndarray` of `TensorVariables`, then you can dump it to a list:

```
a = np.array([tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*1, tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*2])

res = tt.gt(a.tolist(), 1)
res.eval()
# array([False, True])
```

However, if you can, I would avoid NumPy altogether.

```
a = [tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*1, tt.as_tensor_variable(1)*2]

res = tt.gt(a, 1)
res.eval()
# array([False, True])
```

Even better, the `TensorVariable` type already has full support for multidimensionality, and sticking to methods in `theano.tensor`, one will get more efficient performance than moving back and forth to `list` or `ndarray` objects.  For example,

```
a = tt.as_tensor([1,2])

res = tt.gt(a, 1)
res.eval()
# array([False, True])
```

Comment: Thank you !   Actually I'm using an existing model function developed with numpy and pandas, thus I would like to not rewrite everything in theano..